# C++11 How to cast enum class template parameter to int?

Tags: c++11, templates, casting, template-meta-programming, enum-class

I have a struct which takes enum class value on the template parameter.

```
template <typename EnumValue>
struct Type
{
public:
    static constexpr int VALUE = static_cast<int>(EnumValue);
};

enum class MyEnum {Val1, Val2};

std::cout << Type<MyEnum::Val2>::VALUE << std::endl;
```

I expected it to work, but it gives errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     static constexpr int VALUE = static_cast<int>(EnumValue);

error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class EnumValue> struct Type’
  std::cout << Type<MyEnum::Val2>::VALUE << std::endl;
```

How to fix these errors without changing the template parameters for Type?

Since I don't want the template inputs to be changed,
I don't want to use something like this:

```
template <typename EnumType, EnumType EnumValue>
struct Type...
```

Comment: How about creating another class template like `template <int N> Helper` and then go with `Type<Helper<MyEnum::Val2> >`? Drops any information on from which enum it came, though, might not work out depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Aziuth enum class is not implicitly convertible to int and it needs cast.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't.

`typename EnumValue` declares a *type*, it is not a value. You can't have `Type<MyEnum::Val2>` with an `enum class` in C++11.

In C++17 you will be able to write `template <auto EnumValue>` which does what you want.

Comment: Isn't there a way to implement using helper structs? or
Is there no way to use this solution in c++11?

Comment: I can't use C++17 in my project

Comment: @MojtabaShahbazi you need two template parameters, one for the type, the other for the value. If you could do it otherwise, [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) would have

Answer (score 0):

As @Caleth has mentioned, you need to specify the enum type and enum value to the `Type` struct. But as far as you do not want to change the template parameters, why not going for an static method inside `Type`?

```
template <typename EnumType>
struct Type
{
public:
   static constexpr int getValue(EnumType value)
   {
      return static_cast<int>(value);
   }
};

enum class MyEnum { Val1, Val2 };


int main()
{
   std::cout << Type<MyEnum>::getValue(MyEnum::Val2) << std::endl;
}
```